# Rails is there a way to say @object.created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to know if rails has a method that allows me to determine if the object is built but not created in the db or has been created?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `new_record?` method:

Use it like:

```
object.new_record?
```

This will tell you that the object has been created, but not saved to the database yet.

Comment: Ha! 10 second lead. Well played. +1

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @RyanWilcox, you can also use [persisted?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F).

From the documentation:

> Returns if the record is persisted,
>   i.e. it’s not a new record and it was
>   not destroyed.